# Rails 5 + Mongoid virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid6

I am trying to make a simple user signup functionality with Rails 5 and Mongoid. My user model and controller look like this:

user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false

  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation

  field :email, type: String
  field :password, type: String
  ...
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
...
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    json_response(nil, nil, :created)
  else
    json_response(@user.errors.full_messages, nil, :bad_request)
  end
end
...
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)
  end
```

Now I need to check if the password_confirmation is the same as password, both params are send through the request, but password_confirmation is not passed to the new user object, altought it is whitelisted in strong parameters:

log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-02 13:03:10 +0200
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", email"=>"test@mail.com", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

I don't want to add

```
field :password_confirmation
```

to my model, which solves this problem. I just need to make the attribute virtual and get rid of it after validation. What am I missing or doing wrong? Or what is the correct attitude to this?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add it as an `attr_acessor`

```
Class User
...
field :email, type: String
field :password, type: String
attr_accessor :password_confirmation
...
end
```

You'll be able to access it, but it will not be persisted.

Comment: unfortunatelly this does not help, it seems that `params.require(:user).permit(...)` can only work with those attributes defined by `field` and it ignores `attr_accessor`

Comment: Well, as a last resort you can add it as a field, but prevent it from saving by creating a before_save filter to nil it. It's ugly but will work.